# Fixing "error: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2" in Android Kernel build

Tags: java, android-build, android-12, android-kernel

I'm building Android 12 ROM for a device `(codename: fajita)`. During the kernel build, it shows the below error for several jar files.

```
[  0% 338/44436] Verifying uses-libraries: vendor/oneplus/fajita/proprietary/framework/com.qti.dpmframework.jar
FAILED: /home/mn/git/evox/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.qti.dpmframework_intermediates/enforce_uses_libraries.status
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f /home/mn/git/evox/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.qti.dpmframework_intermediates/enforce_uses_libraries.status ) && (build/soong/scripts/manifest_check.py      --enforc
e-uses-libraries      --enforce-uses-libraries-status /home/mn/git/evox/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.qti.dpmframework_intermediates/enforce_uses_libraries.status     --aapt /home/mn/
git/evox/out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt                      vendor/oneplus/fajita/proprietary/framework/com.qti.dpmframework.jar )"
error: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2
```

The same error shows for other jar files as well, such as `com.qualcomm.qti.camera.jar`, `com.qti.location.sdk.jar` and 7 more.

Upon decompiling the jar files using [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/), the components seems well formed.

[image]

I tried building with `RELAX_USES_LIBRARY_CHECK := true` to force-skip checking on `<uses-libraries>` requirement in Android 12, but also didn't help.

How to solve this error?